# Can you stop reading from a Json in JAVA?

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on a weather application and fetching json-objects from an open API, and wondering if there is any way to stop reading in when before I read in all the information. The JSONfile is pretty big, around 95k characters, and the information I need is in the beginning (first 3-4k). Can I break the read after a certain amount of characters and keep the information I read in so far?

Comment: you can use the condition to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Basically JSON parsing will check for syntax errors. If you need read data like stream way, it may be a better choice to use plain text to read by line. I don't know if there is a better JSON parser support for this operation. If the JSON is a big array we can split the string first.